# Looping arrays in Javascript (novice)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

I'm very new to JavaScript coding, and have an assignment to complete, with no clue how to do it. I must loop an array holding random numbers, and write the number directly from the array to the string. How would I begin looping arrays? I feel like I've tried everything. 
Here's something I tried:

```
    var num = new Array();

num[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);

for (i = 0; i < 20;i++);
{
document.write(num[i]);
}
```

This is the easiest part of the assignment but I can't even grasp this. Anyone?

Comment: You're using `num[i]` outside of the loop; do you need to generate 20 random numbers?

Comment: I'd suggest you go over [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). They have some excellent Javascript tutorials that will introduce you to the basics (control flow, conditionals, arrays etc.)

Comment: You forgot to declare `i` with a `var` statement, making `i` an implied global. An accidental global, especially one with a common name such as `i`, can cause lots of infuriating bugs. It would be good to use [strict mode](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/), it will give you errors when you create an implied global so you can fix it before it causes you headaches. [jshint](http://jshint.com/) or [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) can also be helpful to spot these kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, like that:

```
var i;

// Init an empty array
var arr = [];

// Init an empty string
var someString = "";

// Loop over array and fill it with random integers
for (i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
{
    arr[i] = parseInt(Math.random() * 10);
}

// Loop over array and add its values to string, separated by ';'
for (i = 0; i < 20; i ++)
{
    someString += arr[i] + "; ";
}

// Alert the result
alert(someString);
```

Here is a JSFiddle for testing the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/uPxEf/

Comment: What if I told you that you can generate the array of random numbers like this `Array.apply(null,{length:20}).map(function(){ return Math.random() * 10 << 0;})` ;)

Comment: @thefourtheye, that's cool, but it is not the simplest method for a beginner.